# Remove Specific Type of Children from Grid Control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to remove a suppose control whose type is of border, from the grid control. how can I achieve it in WPF C# ?

Sorry Guys, My problem is that I have grid control which has GUI design at XAML end and user control which are added using C# and the some controls are overlapped. Some controls are removed but some are left which overlap one another. How can I remove all controls. The code you have posted work for control which are not overlapped but for overlapped ones, it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
 int intTotalChildren = grdGrid.Children.Count-1;
            for (int intCounter = intTotalChildren; intCounter > 0; intCounter--)
            {
                if (grdGrid.Children[intCounter].GetType() == typeof(Border))
                {
                    Border ucCurrentChild = (Border)grdGrid.Children[intCounter];
                    grdGrid.Children.Remove(ucCurrentChild);
                }                
            }
```

My error was that each time I used the `Children.Count` in the `for` loop and every time I removed a child, the `Children.Count` changed and not all children were removed.

Comment: There is a bug in this loop—it should be `intCounter >= 0`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could walk the `VisualTree` and remove anything whose type is of `Border`.

```
static public void RemoveVisual(Visual myVisual)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        if(childVisual.GetType() == typeof(Border))
        {
            // Remove Child
        }

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        RemoveVisual(childVisual);
    }
}
```

The removal I leave up to you, but the above should find all controls within a visual of the type `Border`.

Comment: @Asim, was doing so as you added the comment, hehe.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But error was in my code. as I have store total number of children of the grid to separate variable. Thanks for you help. my problem solved now.

Answer (score 0):

try this , grd is the Grid Contol

```
    <Grid x:Name="grd">
    <Border x:Name="test1" Margin="5"
            Background="red"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="5"></Border>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Hello" Click="test"></Button>
</Grid> 

        for(int i=0; i< VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(grd);i++){
Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(grd, i);
if (childVisual is Border)
{
    grd.Children.Remove((UIElement)  childVisual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for remove ALL border controls in a grid children collection

```
    int indice = 0;
    int childrens = TargetGrid.Children.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < childrens; i++)
    {
        Border brd = TargetGrid.Children[indice] as Border;
        if (brd != null)
        {
            //Remove children
            TargetGrid.Children.RemoveAt(indice);
        }
        else
        {
            indice++;
        }
    }
```